# Performance using several conditions AND / OR

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it convenient to use several conditions in some particular order?

I've created the following function, which receives a value per parameter, prints it on screen (OUTPUT), and returns it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jmo_imp (p_value VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(p_value);
  RETURN p_value;
END;
/
```

So, next query returns 45 and also prints 45 on the screen (OUTPUT):

```
SELECT jmo_imp(45) FROM dual
/
```

If I use several conditions separated by the operator "AND" or by the operator "OR", I get the following results printed on the screen (OUTPUT):

```
SELECT 'Hello'
  FROM dual
 WHERE slu.jmo_imp('WHERE1') = 'WHERE1'
   AND slu.jmo_imp('WHERE2') = 'WHERE2'
   AND slu.jmo_imp('WHERE3') = 'WHERE3'
/

WHERE3
WHERE2
WHERE1

SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 1 col FROM dual
        UNION
        SELECT 2 col FROM dual
        UNION
        SELECT 3 col FROM dual
        UNION
        SELECT 4 col FROM dual)
 WHERE slu.jmo_imp(col) = 4
    OR slu.jmo_imp(col) = 3
    OR slu.jmo_imp(col) = 2
    OR slu.jmo_imp(col) = 1
/

1
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
```

That means that whenever I have several conditions separated by the operator "AND" I should use the "most likely" at the end, and if I have several conditions separated by the operator "OR" I should place the "most likely" at the beginning? Or the difference is so tiny that this goes unnoticed for the current versions of Oracle? ("most likely" condition is that one we know/assume will be true more times than the others, and therefore we would avoid evaluating the other conditions).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation: [Condition Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions001.htm#SQLRF52103)

> When evaluating an expression containing multiple conditions, Oracle
>   evaluates conditions with higher precedence before evaluating those
>   with lower precedence. Oracle evaluates conditions with equal
>   precedence from left to right within an expression, with the following
>   exceptions:
>
> - Left to right evaluation is not guaranteed for multiple conditions
>     connected using AND
> - Left to right evaluation is not guaranteed for multiple conditions
>     connected using OR

According to the above, it does not matter what the order of conditions will be in the WHERE clause, this order of evaluation is not guaranted and Oracle is free to evaulate conditions connected with OR and AND operator in any order. 
Even if the tests currently show the order of 3,2,1, there is no guarantee that Oracle will not change this order.

Comment: Also, I believe that `WHERE function(x) = 'y'` will stop any chance of being able to use an index or caching. So you might take a bigger performance hit there.